# Fixing broken update-motd.d folder and files on headless Ubuntu ssh server

Tags: server, ssh, motd

I was trying to fix the motd .d files so that they would display when booting up ssh on my android device and I used an online tutorial to try to fix them.

Now I am unable to test them by typing in `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d` because I keep on getting the following errors.

```
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/update-motd.d/00-header:Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/00-header exited with return code 1
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/update-motd.d/10-sysinfo: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/10-sysinfo exited with return code 1
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/update-motd.d/90-footer: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-footer exited with return code 1
```

Typing in `systemctl status motd` I get this on my screen

```
motd.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Content of file `/etc/update-motd.d/`:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/00-header:  ASCII text
/etc/update-motd.d/10-sysinfo: ASCII text
/etc/update-motd.d/90-footer:  ASCII text
```

Output of `ls -l /etc/update-motd.d/`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1429 Jun  9 14:22 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1927 Jun  9 14:25 10-sysinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2205 Jun  9 14:29 90-footer
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `file /etc/update-motd.d/00-header /etc/update-motd.d/10-sysinfo /etc/update-motd.d/90-footer` please?

Comment: I added some new info regarding the error

Comment: You forgot the `file` command. It is supposed to check the file types of its arguments. I suspect you edited the files from an incompatible system and saved them with a bad encoding (e.g. Windows line endings, or anything not UTF-8)

Comment: I just noticed it was a typo so I get a different output now

Comment: Hmm, in that case, please upload their contents here. and also what `ls -l /etc/update-motd.d/` says.

Comment: Output of file /etc/update-motd.d/. 

/etc/update-motd.d/00-header:  ASCII text
/etc/update-motd.d/10-sysinfo: ASCII text
/etc/update-motd.d/90-footer:  ASCII text

Output of ls -l /etc/update-motd.d/ 

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1429 Jun  9 14:22 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1927 Jun  9 14:25 10-sysinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2205 Jun  9 14:29 90-footer

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem and my mistake was very simple:

i forgot the `#!/bin/sh`